# App.config - LocalSqlServer connection string

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Public Shared Sub SyncConnectionStrings()
    Dim strCon As String
    Dim tyDatabase As typeDatabase
    Dim boolConfigChanged As Boolean
    'Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
    Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
    Dim strConnectionString As ConnectionStringSettings            
    For Each strConnectionString In ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
        'More code here, but irrelevant for this question.
    Next
End Sub
```

The code loops through all the connection strings in the app.config file. There are three connection strings in the `app.config`, but four connection strings are found. Where is: LocalSqlServer (this is the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Name`) defined?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is defined in the Machine.config global file located at

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CONFIG".
```

It is generated when you install the NET.Framework and is needed by tools that work on the ASPNETDB

If you don't need it, you could try to add this to your app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<clear/>
.....
```

or also

```
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
```

I really suggest to not change anything in Machine.Config unless you know the side effects.

Comment: Thanks +1. Do you know if there is a way of looping around the app.config connection strings only?

Comment: Answer updated, not really sure of the side effects, but you could try and if anything goes wrong restore the intial status

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to have more than just the LocalSqlServer in your Machine.config. e.g. I just ran my app on a computer with a MySql connection in Machine.config

You can use the `ElementInformation` property of the `ConnectionStringSetting` to determine where it came from:

```
foreach (ConnectionStringSettings c in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
    ElementInformation elementInfo = c.ElementInformation;
    String source = elementInfo.Source;

    if (source == null)
    {
        //Machine.config
    } 
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", c.Name, elementInfo.Source, c.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```